# Possibility of combining photovoltaics and solar thermal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, photoelectric-effect, thermal-conductivity, absorption, solar-cells

In a private setting, photovoltaics and solar thermal energy are often harvested on the home's roof and roof area is limited. So, I thought about combining both, i.e. mounting solar collectors underneath solar cells. The rationale behind this is that the solar cells appear almost black and probably heat up considerably under irradiation. So if the collectors are in tight thermal contact to the cells, the water in the collectors might carry away the heat as usable energy, and possibly even increase the lifetime or efficiency of the cells due to the cooling effect (but this is rather engineering and not part of the question). So roof area is exploited twice (in two different wavelength windows). Moreover, if electric energy from the cells exceeds actual consumption and the battery's storage capacity, it might also be used for heating (albeit at a lower total efficiency, of course).

Can the amount of (infrared) radiation that gets absorbed (or possibly transmitted) by solar cells, and which is available as heat at the back side of the cells, be quantified by a rough calculation and either prove or disprove the benefit of such a concept? Does the almost black appearance of the solar cells fool one into thinking that they also absorb in the infrared, although they don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperature of PV panels increases significantly during the day and their **conversion efficiency decreases with increasing temperature**. I had access to measurements of a PV plant and it showed that the *total power production* was about the same in August (middle of summer) and October (early fall). Although the days were shorter and there was less solar irradiance in October vs August, the air temperature was significantly lower making PV panels more efficient. For the outside temperature of 35 C, the PV panels can easily reach 70 C!

Here is a map that shows power output of a PV panel versus incident solar irradiance and PV panel temperature. This map was generated from the equivalent (single-diode) model of the PV panel. It is probably a bit difficult to read the map, but just follow the yellow line. Power output at (600 W/m2, 30 C) is about the same as for (700 W/m2, 80 C). These numbers are realistic for a typical summer day - air temperature up to 35 C and PV panel temperature up to 80 C. It takes 15-20% more solar irradiance for the same power output when panels get hot!

[image]

<sup>Figure 1. PV panel maximum power output vs solar irradiance and panel temperature (Source: M. Gulin, PhD Thesis, 2019)</sup>

If you cool down PV panels directly, you might increase their power output and get some usable heat. In order to do so, you would have to mount some heat exchanger on the back of PV panels and there would need to be some fluid flowing which would take the heat. If you take into account that you need to pump this fluid, which also consumes some electricity, with all these benefits the *overall efficiency* would not probably increase by much, if at all! I was mentoring a student a while ago that did their thesis on this topic, and rough calculations showed this concept is not viable. However, they were not considering *heat pumps* in their calculations, just a cold water flowing and taking the heat. The commercial product @annav mentioned in their post probably uses some sort of heat pump to increase efficiency of *taking the heat* from PV panels.

Comment: Thanks for your practical experience. One caveat: if we want to properly compare the photovoltaic yield of two months, we would have to divide by the actual sun hours. Sometimes October is more sunny than August. In Germany they call it "golden October", which, I guess, is not only due to leaves attaining all sorts of colors, but also due to higher likelihood of clear sky. On the other hand, this is probably compensated by the higher angle of incidence in October. So this comparison - and hence the effect of cooling - is not easily eyeballed...

Comment: ... but nevertheless, you are probably right because there is a reason why the average air temp in August is usually much more than in October. And yet I have read somewhere in the past that the negative effect of heat on solar cell efficiency is *not* that dramatic. But the Wikipedia article (and you) seems to say the opposite. Isn't there a formula for that? Like e-to-the-power-of-something from Fermi distribution?

Comment: We were using solar irradiance measurements, so we knew exact numbers for direct and diffuse irradiance in August and October - we were getting much higher numbers in August. There are many uncertainties, but nevertheless it should not be that hard to put down some rough calculations.

Comment: @oliver Maybe I can dig up a graph that shows how power output depends on irradiance and temperature. Let me try..

Comment: @oliver Found the map - it was computer generated from the equivalent (single-diode) model.

Comment: Ah, okay, so there is a significant effect around 30% loss per 100K, equivalent to what you claimed. Impressive! Is this a model or from measurements?

Answer (score 1):

From [this site](https://www.greenmatch.co.uk/blog/2014/11/how-efficient-are-solar-panels) comparing solar panels,

> solar panels are usually able to process 15% to 22% of solar energy into usable energy, depending on factors like placement, orientation, weather conditions, and similar.

As all the energy has to be absorbed, the photovoltaic  if in contact would be loosing only ~20 percent of the direct light so it will depend if it can be placed in contact.

It seems your idea though [is already commercial.](https://dualsun.com/en/product/hybrid-panel-spring/)

Comment: Thanks, I just happened to find the general term "PVT collector" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photovoltaic_thermal_hybrid_solar_collector) for these parts. It seems the problem is mainly that pure thermal collectors typically operate at a higher temperature, and this again is too high for optimally operating the solar cells. So you can either have optimal cooling of the photoelectric cells, or optimal heating of the thermal collectors, or you have to realize a trade-off with reduced efficiency.